# How to run a dll-library in several processes in python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I was trying to run dll-library using Pooling in python and ran into the following problem. I've created a simple dll-library to illustrate the problem. Here's the source code of the dll-library, which contains only one function which sums two double numbers:

```
extern "C" {
  double sum(double x, double y);
}

double sum(double x, double y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

I compile it on a Linux system using

```
g++ -fPIC -c dll_main.cpp
g++ dll_main.o -shared -o sum_dll.so
```

I use this dll-library in the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
from ctypes import *
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

def run_dll(dll_obj, x, y):
    x_c = c_double(x)
    y_c = c_double(y)
    z = dll_obj.sum(x_c, y_c)
    return z

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    dll_obj = cdll.LoadLibrary('./sum_dll.so')
    dll_obj.sum.restype = c_double

    z = pool.map(run_dll, [(dll_obj, 2, 3), (dll_obj, 3, 4)])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

I get the following error-message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run_dll.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "./run_dll.py", line 17, in main
    z = pool.map(run_dll, [(dll_obj, 2, 3), (dll_obj, 3, 4)])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 768, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'CDLL.__init__.<locals>._FuncPtr'
```

What am I doing wrong? How to use dll-library with several processes in python properly?

Comment: I'd guess just don't try to pass the dll between processes, get each process to load their own. The issue is you can't serialise a dll handle

Answer (score 2):

You can't pickle dll pointers, because accessing the dlls requires a systemcall to link them to your process.

since you cannot pass dll functions as arguments, you need to wrap them in a python function, so you should define this function the same way you'd define a normal python function, in the global scope

```py
from ctypes import *
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

dll_obj = cdll.LoadLibrary('./sum_dll.so')
dll_obj.sum.restype = c_double

def pyrun_dll(x, y):  # looks for the dll in global scope
    x_c = c_double(x)
    y_c = c_double(y)
    z = dll_obj.sum(x_c, y_c)
    return z

def dll_sum(x_c, y_c):  # pickleable wrapper
    return dll_obj.sum(x_c, y_c)

def run_dll(py_sum, x, y):  # arguments must be pickleable
    x_c = c_double(x)
    y_c = c_double(y)
    z = py_sum(x_c, y_c)
    return z
```

Then you call these python functions in your main

```py
def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    z = pool.starmap(pyrun_dll, [(2, 3), (3, 4)])
    z2 = pool.starmap(run_dll, [(dll_sum, 2, 3), (dll_sum, 3, 4)])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

the way the above code executes depends on your operating system, but this will work on all platforms (assuming you change the dll name for each platform), because they will either fork the dll reference from the global scope or create one when they import your file.

Your original function will work if you pass `dll_sum` to it, instead of the dll raw function handle.

If you need your dll to be loaded dynamically then you should have each process make the call to cdll to link to the dll itself (usually through the initializer), not get it through a function arguments.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. I get the following error:
TypeError: pyrun_dll() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: @user43283 didn't pay attention to the argument count, [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) should work as i have edited the answer to use it.